# What do I need to setup two DVI monitors on a 2011 Mac Mini

Tags: mac, mac-mini

As a software developer who recently bought an iPhone I knew it was just a matter of time before I started dicking around in the iOS apps space.  Today Apple released a new line of Mac Minis and I am going to buy one.  I'd like to just buy a KVM switch and flip between my current two monitor PC setup and the Mac.  What kind of adapters do I need for the Mac Mini to be able to take two DVI outs?

Answer (score 0):

For DVI, this is impossible. The back of the new Mac mini has an HDMI and a Thunderbolt adapter.  You can daisy chain thunderbolts, but not HDMI.  And I know of zero KVMs that accept HDMI along with zero KVMs that accept Thunderbolt.

I offer a better solution.  Lion now allows you to run it in a VM.  If you already have a copy, I'd just fire that up. . .

Comment: Can't I get an HDMI to DVI adapter?

Comment: Yes, but that only gets you one monitor.  AFAIK, there is no thunderbolt to DVI adapter. . .

Answer (score 0):

If you have two DVI monitors you need the following:

1 - HDMI to DVI adaptor
http://www.amazon.co.uk/female-Monitor-Display-Adapter-Converter/dp/B0021Y7FY2/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1311199217&sr=1-1

2 - Mini-displayport to DVI adaptor
(this should work fine, it's listed on the thunderbolt mac-mini specs page - http://www.apple.com/macmini/specs.html)
http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB570Z/A

That should workout fine for dual displays - but may be worth getting a demo at a local Apple Store.

Comment: Odd, I don't see the minidisplay port on the Mac Mini or the Thunderbolt display.  It isn't on the specs, nor is it on the picture for either one . . .